# Access variable Element of Array in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I want to get the Value of an array at an variable index. The Index is computed by the program and not known at parse time. So it is stored in an Value and converted to an Int like this:

```
Value *IndexV = Index->Codegen();
Value *IntV = Builder.CreateFPToUI( IndexV, Type::getInt32Ty( getGlobalContext() ) );
```

If I know the index, I can use:

```
Value *VV = Builder.CreateExtractValue( Builder.CreateLoad( V ), 0 );
```

This gives me the first element of the array. And works correctly. But how can I use `IntV` as the index? `CreateExtractValue` only takes an ArrayRef and there is no way of casting the `IntV` to an ArrayRef, or am I wrong? How would one do such a thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, whenever an ArrayRef is expected, you can always pass just a single item, as there's [an implicit conversion](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ArrayRef_8h_source.html#l00053) between any `T` and `ArrayRef<T>`.

Specifically here, though, [extractvalue](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#extractvalue-instruction) requires constant indices, and cannot accept general values, which is why it wants `unsigned` values. If you want to access an element in an unknown index in an array, use a [getelementptr](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#getelementptr-instruction) instruction instead: invoke it on the address of the array with indices 0 and `IntV`, and you should get a pointer to the array at location `IntV`.

Comment: This give me an compiling error: `error: no viable conversion from 'llvm::Value *' to 'ArrayRef<unsigned int>'`

Comment: @Philip my bad, I confused `extractvalue` with `extractelement` (which does accept `Value` indices). I updated my answer - I think you want a GEP here.